# How do I search only one column for a value instead of searching the whole sheet.

Tags: excel, vba

The macro I am using opens an input box where you can enter what you are searching for and when it finds the value it highlights the entire row. The only problem is that it searches the entire sheet and not just one column. I want it to only search in Column B otherwise the search is pointless as it picks up values matching in other columns.

Here is the code I am using.

```
Sub Seroquel_25000_1mod1()
Dim SrchRng3 As Range

Dim c3 As Range, f As String

Set SrchRng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("B8", ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
AGAIN:
srchItem = InputBox("Please Enter the product CODE", "Product Search")
Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find(srchItem, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
f = c3.Address
With Range("B" & c3.Row & ":M" & c3.Row)
.Select
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Floris: You are right. The above code should work.

Comment: Are you sure the above code doesn't work. I just tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: Hey @Siddharth Rout, thanks for answering the question but it still searches the entire table for some reason.

Comment: My data is in a table (Columns B:M) (Rows (8:522). Is the code not working because it is a table? Should I convert it to a range?

Comment: Is your data in regular cells, some merged cells, a named range or an actual Excel Table?

Comment: I believe it is an actual excel table, with headers

Comment: `I believe it is...` Let's make that sure :) Can you upload the file on a file sharing site and then share the link here?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a table, you will want to use the table name and field name to specify the search range:

```
Set SrchRng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("tablename[fieldname]")
```

If you don't know the table name, one way to find it is by clicking any cell in the table and then looking at the Design tab.  The field name is the text of the header cell above that column in the table. [Here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) is a decent reference on how to refer to tables and table data in VBA.

Comment: @user2970072 If you'll pardon my asking, how do you know that all the cells in the table are searched and not just the ones in the specified range? Does it find matches outside of that range?

Comment: yes it finds matches outside the range so instead of finding item 500 in column B it finds an entry in column E or G that has 500 in it.

Comment: OK guys thank you so much for all your help. It turns out my computer is insane and now that I re-added the same macro it works. Just one of those things. Again appreciate everyone taking time to help.